# How do I set the response header when implementing download file via RestController?

Tags: spring-boot, download, swagger

```
public interface IndexApi {
    @ApiOperation(value = "Download excel.", response = byte[].class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "The excel file", response = byte[].class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected error", response = String.class)})
    @GetMapping(
            value = "/api/download",
            produces = {"application/vnd.ms-excel"})
    byte[] download();
}

@RestController
public class TestController implements Api {
        @Override
        public byte[] download() {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefile.xls\"");
            return service.download(symbol);
        }
    }
```

When I implemented this, it'll download the file just fine but the file name will be download. How can I set the header so that I can customize the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Download file.",            
        response = byte[].class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "File download.", response = byte[].class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected error", response = String.class)})
@GetMapping(
        value = "/file/{exDate}/download",
        produces = {"application/vnd.ms-excel"})
public byte[] download(@ApiParam(value = "Valid date.", required = true) @PathVariable(value = "exDate") String exDate, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + String.format(FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE, dateArg[0],dateArg[1],dateArg[2]));
    return service.download(exDate);
}
```

Had to set the `produces` parameter to `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `ResponseEntity`object with the headerscset and pass the stream of the file to the `ResponseEntity`